# Angular open component in new window without bootstraping

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I would like to open a component in a new window but without to bootstrap again.
In my case I am using a popup from devextreme, but I would like to open and hide a window like I would do it with a popup or dialog. The benefit of a window is that it can be used outside and parallel. But the first time the window reopens ot is to slow.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunatly no.. The hole application is reloaded, the only benefit is that all src are cached in the browser and so the second time they are loaded faster

Answer (score 0):

Opening a new window for an angular application actually breaks the Single Page Application philosophy. However, there can be a usecase to open a component in different window.

One way is to use **sessions**. Sessions are something which are maintained throughout the browser. So when you, say click a button, you can store a variable in session. Now when the new window is opened, use the session variable you stored to create a logic of routing to your component.

Bootstrapping of application is still there, but it loads your component. I am not sure if this can be done without bootstrapping.